# Query for Most Recent activity is failure

Tags: postgresql

I have pondered over related posts and just cannot obtain success.  I need to have a report that shows the last note for a client.  I am really close, but the query routinely "misses" the actual last entry.  Let's say I run the report to show the last entry in the past 6 months and is shows the last entry for "bob" as 8/1/13.  When I look in the table, there is a note on 10/23/13.  I checked to see if somehow the data was messed up, but it looks good.  If anyone can shed some light why I have a number of "almost last notes" in the query instead of the actual most current one, I'd be very appreciative.              Here is the query I used with comments explaining it:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT ON (c.client_id) --the client id
g.name, -- the office location
MAX (n.date_service),
n.date_creation, 
sv.code, -- the service / activity code
c.name_lastfirst_cs, -- client's name
n.date_service,  
s.staff_id -- staff id
FROM  notes n, clients c, services sv,  staff s, groups g
WHERE n.zrud_service = sv.zzud_service
AND n.visibility_flag = '1' -- 1 = valid note
AND n.zrud_client = c.zzud_client
AND n.zrud_staff = s.zzud_staff
AND n.zrud_group = g.zzud_group
AND g.name = 'HALIFAX' -- am specifying a single location

-- the next 4 lines were an attempt to query specific time range and actitity codes
--AND s.code IN ('10101', '10102', '10201',     10202','10203','10204','10205','10401','10402','10403','10405')
-- AND n.date_service >= '1/1/2010'
-- AND n.date_service<= '11/7/2013'
-- AND n.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '800 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now() 

GROUP BY g.name,sv.code, c.client_id, c.name_lastfirst_cs, s.staff_id,
n.date_service, n.date_creation
```

Comment: why there's no order by clause in your query? you have to have `order by c.client_id, max(n.date_service) desc` to get last row for client_id

Comment: `Query for Most Recent activity is failure` You should start writing poetry.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for the encouragement in a sideline of prose and poetry.  However, Alas! my command of the written language is pale in comparison to the likes of Emerson, Poe, and Dickenson.  If I can just get a solid working knowledge of postgresql I would be happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want a last entry based on `some_date` on a table, using `DISTINCT ON` together with `ORDER BY some_date DESC` is a good option:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT ON (c.client_id) --the client id
g.name, -- the office location
n.date_service,
n.date_creation, 
sv.code, -- the service / activity code
c.name_lastfirst_cs, -- client's name
n.date_service,  
s.staff_id -- staff id
FROM  notes n, clients c, services sv,  staff s, groups g
WHERE n.zrud_service = sv.zzud_service
AND n.visibility_flag = '1' -- 1 = valid note
AND n.zrud_client = c.zzud_client
AND n.zrud_staff = s.zzud_staff
AND n.zrud_group = g.zzud_group
AND g.name = 'HALIFAX' -- am specifying a single location
ORDER BY c.client_id, n.date_service DESC;
```

Note that there is no need of `GROUP BY` nor `MAX`, the `DISTINCT ON` took care of grouping and `ORDER BY` of retrieving only the last entry.